# Calling a function only one time while submiting

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am trying to submit a form and while submitting I call a function which is `myOwnFun` and it runs. But if I keep pressing enter  for long time, form submit repeats which I don't want.

Here is the code..

```
<form class="user__answer-form">
     <input type="text" name="useranswer" class="user__answer">
</form>
```

```
const form = document.querySelector('.user__answer-form');
const formAnswer = document.querySelector('.user__answer');

formAnswer.focus();

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   myOwnFun();
});


function myOwnFun() {
   console.log('show text one time in one Enter')
}
```

I want to run this function only one time when I press enter even if I pressed for longer time. And I need to submit the form many different times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.user__answer-form');
const formAnswer = document.querySelector('.user__answer');

//create a counter to track key down events
let count  = 0;

formAnswer.focus();

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   //call your function only if count is 0 
   //ie is first time enter key is pressed 
   
   //if key is pressed for  a long time count > 0 
   // this condition fails
   if(count == 1){
     myOwnFun();
   }    
    
});

//fires on any key is pressed on form element
form.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    // for cross browser compatibility
    const keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

   if(keyCode == 13){
      //if enter key is pressed update count 
      count ++;
   }
});

//fires on  key is released on form element
form.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

      const keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
      //if enter key is released reset the count
      if(keyCode == 13){
        count = 0
      }

});



function myOwnFun() {
    console.log('show text one time in one Enter');
}
```

```html
<form class="user__answer-form" >
     <input type="text" name="useranswer" class="user__answer">
</form>
```

Comment: It works if I press Enter for the first time But I need to press Enter many different times.

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.preventDefault()` method in your script first and then in your code, this will disable the default functionality of form and executing your code.

Comment: I am already adding e.preventDefault()  inside the function on addEventListener.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const form = document.querySelector('.user__answer-form');
const formAnswer = document.querySelector('.user__answer');

formAnswer.focus();

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   myOwnFun();
});


function myOwnFun() {
 var executed = false;
    return function() {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
            console.log('show text one time in one Enter')
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use that: `form.removeEventListener("submit", yourFunction);`

I think you'll have to change `function(e)` to a "real function" to make it work

Answer (score 1):

As a "throw a library/package at it" solution, Lodash has a `once` function that restricts the function to one call per page load: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#once. Might be a bit overkill, especially if you just need it in the one line, so I would recommend it as a last resort, even if you go with the standalone package.